# emacs/elisp setup files when loaded

Tags: emacs, elisp

I found that the elisp (emacs elisp) doesn't seem to read .bashrc, as the PATH variable is different from the one set in .bashrc, as I asked in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621755/what-setup-file-does-eshell-elisp-shell-read-when-it-starts-how-eshell-sets-i). I tried to load .bashrc using 'source .bashrc' in elisp, but when I do, elisp just quits.

- What files does elisp read when being loaded?
- Is there any way that I can use the setups that I made in .bashrc (alias, PATH, ...)?

#### SOLUTION

Gilles gave me a good answer, and with the PATH, it depends on how I start the Aquamcs.

- When I click the button to start Aquamacs, it has different PATH.
- When I run 'aquamacs' from the command line, it has the same PATH.

Comment: as I said on SO, `.bashrc` is not the right place to set `PATH` or other environment variables, and which place is right depends on your OS and other environment information which you haven't provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aliases are a shell-specific concept, so bash aliases don't carry over to eshell. Eshell has its own alias system, documented in comments near the top of `em-alias.el`. In a nutshell, you define aliases with the `alias` commands, and they are stored automatically for future sessions. The syntax is not the same as `bash`, for example you would write `alias l='ls -l $*'` in eshell where you write `alias ls='ls -l'` in bash. Alias definitions live in a file called `~/.eshell/alias` where `"~/.eshell"` is the value of `eshell-directory-name`.

Eshell also has a shell function system, documented in comments near the top of `esh-cmd.el`. Quoting the first paragraph:

> Whenever a command is specified using a simple name, such as 'ls',
>   Eshell will first look for a Lisp function of the name `eshell/ls'.
>   If it exists, it will be called in preference to any other command
>   which might have matched the name 'ls' (such as command aliases,
>   external commands, Lisp functions of that name, etc).