# Directories appearing twice in $PATH

Tags: linux, bash, gnome

Following advice from a course, I added the following line to my .bashrc:

```
export PATH=/home/dodgycoder/kafka_2.12-2.3.1/bin:$PATH
```

Now, when I open a terminal window I get this directory shown twice:

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/dodgycoder/kafka_2.12-2.3.1/bin:/home/dodgycoder/kafka_2.12-2.3.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:...
```

Why is this? What's the correct way to add a directory to your PATH?

I'm using Fedora with the Gnome desktop. I confirm I only have the above line just *once* in my .bashrc and it's not defined anywhere else.

Comment: Try adding another line: `export PARENTS="[$PPID/$(</proc/$PPID/comm)],$PARENTS"`, then it'll end up having the names of every process which invoked bash along the way.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you have here is the way you did add the PATH component.

When you add a directory to PATH, it could already be present. There are two options in that case : 1) Do not add it again, or 2) remove+add it.

I use the (2), as I prefer to control the directories order in PATH.

To avoid this problem, I use a couple of functions in my .bashrc, which allow to add a directory at beginning or end of PATH, keeping only one occurrence of it.

A way to define these functions could be :

```bsh
# _remove $1 from PATH
_path_del() {
    local _l=":$PATH:"
    while [[ $_l =~ :$1: ]]; do
          _l=${_l//:$1:/:}
    done
    _l=${_l%:}
    _l=${_l#:}
    PATH="$_l"
}

# _prepend : prepend $1 to PATH.
_path_prepend() {
    _path_del "$1"
    PATH="$1:$PATH"
}

# _append : append $1 to PATH.
_path_append() {
    _path_del "$1"
    PATH="$PATH:$1"
}
```

Usage example :

```bsh
# possible initial PATH
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin

# append ~/bin if it exists
[[ -d "$HOME/bin" ]] && _path_append "$HOME/bin"
printf "%s\n" "$PATH"
# prepend ~/bin if it exists
[[ -d "$HOME/bin" ]] && _path_prepend "$HOME/bin"
printf "%s\n" "$PATH"
```

Output:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/home/br/bin
/home/br/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin
```

**EDIT** : If you don't care the order of new directory in PATH, and prefer the (slightly faster) solution (1), you could try something like :

```bsh
[[ :$PATH: =~ :$newpath: ]] || PATH="$newpath:$PATH"  # prepend
[[ :$PATH: =~ :$newpath: ]] || PATH="$PATH:$newpath"  # append
```

Answer (score 0):

`.bashrc` is not the best place to set `$PATH` or any other environment variable,
since it may be invoked more than once.

Environment variables had better be set in `~/.profile`.

See the following posts:

- [Which setup files should be used for setting up environment variables with bash?](https://superuser.com/questions/183845/which-setup-files-should-be-used-for-setting-up-environment-variables-with-bash/183956)
- [Difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile/183980).